# Django1.11 Customized UserCreationForm filter email

Tags: python, django, authentication, django-forms

I am trying to filter user's alias. I am using Django's userform and its authentication.

`forms.py`

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class SignupForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.CharField(
        retuired=True,
        widget=EmailInput(
            attrs={'class':'validate',}
        )
    )
```

`views.py`

```
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth import login as auth_login

def signup(req):
    if req.method == "POST":
        form = UserCreationForm(req.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save()
            auth_login(req, user)
            return redirect('home')
    else:
        form = UserCreationForm()
    context = {
        'form':form,
    }
    return render(req, "signup.html", context)
```

I believe that I need to filter inside of `views.py`. 
 For example, if I want to filter alias which is not gmail, they cannot signup. How can I filter email?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `clean_<field_name>` method.

```
def clean_email(self):
    email = self.cleaned_data['email']
    if not email.endswith('gmail.com'):
       raise forms.ValidationError("Invalid email", code='invalid email')
    return email
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-a-specific-field-attribute